# JQuery refresh select box

Tags: jquery, select, jquery-mobile

I am populating a select field using JQuery on page load using this method

```
 $('#select').append('<option value="' + result + '">' + result + '</option>');
```

However this leaves the select box 'blank', i.e the first value in the options list is not preselected as the selected option.

How do I 'refresh' this list so that the first value is preselected?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can add a "selected" attribute to the option element you'd like to be selected:

```
$('#select')
    .append('<option value="' + result + '" selected="selected">' + result + '</option>');
```

You don't specify how you populate exactly you select element, using a loop, you could do like this:

```
var data = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var $select = $('#select'); // you might wanna empty it first with .empty()

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var o = $('<option/>', { value: data[i] })
        .text(data[i])
        .prop('selected', i == 0);
    o.appendTo($select);
}​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/EU7Pc/)**

---

So it seems you are using jQuery Mobile like you said in the comment.

If you are using the selectmenu *widget*, you need to programmatically refresh after you make programmatic change to its content/structure:

```
$select.selectmenu("refresh", true);
```

**[Documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/forms/selects/methods.html)**

Comment: Perhaps this is a problem with JQuery mobile forms select fields as none of these examples are pre selecting a value, yes in that (for example on an iPhone, when you view the select for there is a blue tick next to the selected value) but on the load the select box is white. Very odd.

Comment: You should specify you are using jquery mobile, this is pretty important information ! Are you using the selectmenu widget ?

Comment: @DidierGhys The DEMO fiddle isn't working for me, it just says the page doesn't exist.

Answer (score 5):

You may use

```
$('#select').removeAttr('selected').find('option:first').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Comment: Perhaps this is a problem with JQuery mobile forms select fields as none of these examples are pre selecting a value, yes in that (for example on an iPhone, when you view the select for there is a blue tick next to the selected value) but on the load the select box is white. Very odd.

Answer (score 4):

Simply .. you set the value whatever you want , i.e : `$('#select').val(5);` .. so in your case its `$('#select').val(result);`

Edit : a full working example included :

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.js'></script>
<select id='select'></select>
<br>
<input type=button onclick='addNew()' value='Add'>

<script>
function addNew()
{
        var result = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000);
        $('#select').append('<option value="' + result + '">' + result + '</option>'); 
        $('#select').val(result);           
} 
</script>
```

​

Comment: I'm afraid that's not solving it, still empty preselected option :(

Comment: Perhaps this is a problem with JQuery mobile forms select fields as none of these examples are pre selecting a value, yes in that (for example on an iPhone, when you view the select for there is a blue tick next to the selected value) but on the load the select box is white. Very odd.

Answer (score 4):

Hi after several research, I solved with this piece of code:

```
$('#select_id').empty();    
$('#select_id').append($('<option>',{text: 'pippo', value: 'pippo', selected: true}))
$('#select_id').change();
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Not all browsers refresh select automatically after you add a new option.

One trick which works for me is hiding and showing the select box just after adding new options to it. So in your case:

```
 $('#select').append('<option value="' + result + '">' + result + '</option>').hide().show();
```

As for selecting the correct newly added option, follow with:

```
 $('select').val(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

[Mohora Bogdan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9380897/6679820)'s answer only works once, then if you select another option it doesn't work any more.

In order to make it reusable use :

```
$('#select').prop('selected', false).find('option:first').prop('selected', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#ControlIDHere').val('YourValueHere');
$('#ControlIDHere').change();
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has a few answers—including one that has been reasonably validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?